# Fixed height of both the cards in the flex in tailwindCSS?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Basically, I have two cards side by side, and I want them to be of the same height irrespective of the content inside.

Here below is the code shared of the same.

**Please solve for the large screen view.**

### What I Want

The top right card for the Second Semester is the max height I had, and I want all the cards in the same height irrespective of the different/less content.

### Code

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-2 sm:p-10 flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center space-y-3 lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-16 justify-center w-full">
                
                <div
                  initial={{ opacity: 0.3 }}
                  whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
                  class="card w-full h-full bg-transparent hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover: hover:to-[#b2eff7] transition hover:rounded-lg hover:drop-shadow-3xl hover:ease-in-oute "
                >
                  <div class="transition p-2 flex flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffa0ae,5%] to-[#b2eff7]  rounded-lg border shadow-md sm:flex-row  hover:cursor-pointer hover:from-[#ffa0ae,5%] hover:to-[#b2eff7] hover:transition hover:duration-500 ease-in-out  opacity-90 hover:opacity-100">
                    <!-- {/* main content */} -->
                    <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
                      <!-- {/* heading */} -->
                      <div class="flex flex-wrap sm:mx-auto sm:mb-2 -mx-2">
                        <div class="p-2 ">
                          <div class=" rounded-lg flex p-4 h-full justify-center items-center">
                            <svg
                              fill="none"
                              stroke="currentColor"
                              stroke-linecap="round"
                              stroke-linejoin="round"
                              stroke-width="3"
                              class="text-indigo-500 w-6 h-6 flex-shrink-0 mr-4"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                              <path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 11-5.93-9.14"></path>
                              <path d="M22 4L12 14.01l-3-3"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="title-font text-blue-900 text-lg tracking-wide font-medium">
                              First Semester | 2020-21
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- {/* table */} -->
                      <div class="lg:px-4 lg:pb-2">
                        <table class="table-auto lg:w-full text-left whitespace-no-wrap">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100/50 rounded-tl rounded-bl w-1/5">
                                Code
                              </th>
                              <th class="px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100/50 w-4/5">
                                Name
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="text-gray-800 bg-gray-50/25">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">EN 409</td>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">Mathematical Foundation for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">EN 409</td>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">Mathematical Foundation for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- {/* card2 chessmania*/} -->
                <div
                  initial={{ opacity: 0.3 }}
                  whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
                  class="card w-full h-full bg-transparent hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover: hover:to-[#b2eff7] transition hover:rounded-lg hover:drop-shadow-3xl hover:ease-in-oute "
                >
                  <div class="transition p-2 flex flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffa0ae,5%] to-[#b2eff7]  rounded-lg border shadow-md sm:flex-row  hover:cursor-pointer hover:from-[#ffa0ae,5%] hover:to-[#b2eff7] hover:transition hover:duration-500 ease-in-out  opacity-90 hover:opacity-100">
                    <!-- {/* main content */} -->
                    <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
                      <!-- {/* heading */} -->
                      <div class="flex flex-wrap sm:mx-auto sm:mb-2 -mx-2">
                        <div class="p-2 ">
                          <div class=" rounded-lg flex p-4 h-full justify-center items-center">
                            <svg
                              fill="none"
                              stroke="currentColor"
                              stroke-linecap="round"
                              stroke-linejoin="round"
                              stroke-width="3"
                              class="text-indigo-500 w-6 h-6 flex-shrink-0 mr-4"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                              <path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 11-5.93-9.14"></path>
                              <path d="M22 4L12 14.01l-3-3"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="title-font text-blue-900 text-lg tracking-wide font-medium">
                              Second Semester | 2020-21
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- {/* table */} -->
                      <div class="lg:px-4 lg:pb-2">
                        <table class="table-auto lg:w-full text-left whitespace-no-wrap">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100/50 rounded-tl rounded-bl w-1/5">
                                Code
                              </th>
                              <th class="px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100/50 w-4/5">
                                Name
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="text-gray-800 bg-gray-50/25">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">EN 409</td>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">Mathematical Foundation for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">EN 409</td>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">Mathematical Foundation for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">EN 409</td>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">Mathematical Foundation for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>   
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="p-2 sm:p-10 flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center space-y-3 lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-16 justify-center w-full">
                
                <div
                  initial={{ opacity: 0.3 }}
                  whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
                  class="card w-full h-full bg-transparent hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover: hover:to-[#b2eff7] transition hover:rounded-lg hover:drop-shadow-3xl hover:ease-in-oute "
                >
                  <div class="transition p-2 flex flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffa0ae,5%] to-[#b2eff7]  rounded-lg border shadow-md sm:flex-row  hover:cursor-pointer hover:from-[#ffa0ae,5%] hover:to-[#b2eff7] hover:transition hover:duration-500 ease-in-out  opacity-90 hover:opacity-100">
                    <!-- {/* main content */} -->
                    <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
                      <!-- {/* heading */} -->
                      <div class="flex flex-wrap sm:mx-auto sm:mb-2 -mx-2">
                        <div class="p-2 ">
                          <div class=" rounded-lg flex p-4 h-full justify-center items-center">
                            <svg
                              fill="none"
                              stroke="currentColor"
                              stroke-linecap="round"
                              stroke-linejoin="round"
                              stroke-width="3"
                              class="text-indigo-500 w-6 h-6 flex-shrink-0 mr-4"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                              <path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 11-5.93-9.14"></path>
                              <path d="M22 4L12 14.01l-3-3"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="title-font text-blue-900 text-lg tracking-wide font-medium">
                              third Semester | 2020-21
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- {/* table */} -->
                      <div class="lg:px-4 lg:pb-2">
                        <table class="table-auto lg:w-full text-left whitespace-no-wrap">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100/50 rounded-tl rounded-bl w-1/5">
                                Code
                              </th>
                              <th class="px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100/50 w-4/5">
                                Name
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="text-gray-800 bg-gray-50/25">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">EN 409</td>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">Mathematical Foundation for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">EN 409</td>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">Mathematical Foundation for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- {/* card2 chessmania*/} -->
                <div
                  initial={{ opacity: 0.3 }}
                  whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
                  class="card w-full h-full bg-transparent hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover: hover:to-[#b2eff7] transition hover:rounded-lg hover:drop-shadow-3xl hover:ease-in-oute "
                >
                  <div class="transition p-2 flex flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffa0ae,5%] to-[#b2eff7]  rounded-lg border shadow-md sm:flex-row  hover:cursor-pointer hover:from-[#ffa0ae,5%] hover:to-[#b2eff7] hover:transition hover:duration-500 ease-in-out  opacity-90 hover:opacity-100">
                    <!-- {/* main content */} -->
                    <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
                      <!-- {/* heading */} -->
                      <div class="flex flex-wrap sm:mx-auto sm:mb-2 -mx-2">
                        <div class="p-2 ">
                          <div class=" rounded-lg flex p-4 h-full justify-center items-center">
                            <svg
                              fill="none"
                              stroke="currentColor"
                              stroke-linecap="round"
                              stroke-linejoin="round"
                              stroke-width="3"
                              class="text-indigo-500 w-6 h-6 flex-shrink-0 mr-4"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                              <path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 11-5.93-9.14"></path>
                              <path d="M22 4L12 14.01l-3-3"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="title-font text-blue-900 text-lg tracking-wide font-medium">
                              Fourth Semester | 2020-21
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- {/* table */} -->
                      <div class="lg:px-4 lg:pb-2">
                        <table class="table-auto lg:w-full text-left whitespace-no-wrap">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100/50 rounded-tl rounded-bl w-1/5">
                                Code
                              </th>
                              <th class="px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100/50 w-4/5">
                                Name
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="text-gray-800 bg-gray-50/25">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">EN 407</td>
                              <td class="px-2 py-3">Chemistry for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">EN 409</td>
                              <td class=" px-2 py-1">Mathematical Foundation for Energy Science</td>
                            </tr>   
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `items-stretch` on the flex container after doing try&error for 2 hours.  Also, I have a wrapper on those cards, so also `h-full` will be needed on every card.

Here's the code

https://play.tailwindcss.com/kcMpap5MWd?layout=horizontal